# problem with getDerivedStateFromProps when child component make setstate in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components. `Grandparent`, `Parent` and `Child`.
if a data change in `Grandparent` I pass it to `Parent` as a prop so I can trigger change in `Parent` and set new data to its state using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userId : this.props.userId
    }
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.userId !== prevState.userId)
      return {
        userId : this.props.userId
      }
    return null
  }
  getDataFromChild(value){
    this.setState({
      userId: value
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <Child onChange={(value) => this.getDataFromChild(value)} />
    )
  }
}
```

there is also a prop in `Child` component called `onChange`. When a data change in `Child` Component I use `this.props.onChange(data)` to passing it to parent.
so I want to store this data in Parent's state.

```
export class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userId: this.props.userId
    }
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.userId !== prevState.userId)
      return {
        userId: this.props.userId
      }
    return null
  }
  async passToParent(value) {
    await this.setState({
      userId: value
    })
    this.props.onChange(value)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.passToParent(e.target.value)} value={this.state.userId}/>
    )
  }
}
```

the problem is when any states or props change in `Parent` component, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is triggered and because `nextprops.userId` is not equal to `prevState`(new state that has been set by `Child`), the old userId(comes from `Grandparent`) set to state.
what should I do.
sorry for my bad english skill.

Comment: once the `Child` component sets the state in `Parent`, you don't want the state from `GrandParent` to affect it?

Comment: No I don't want.
I want `Child` can sets the state in `Parent` but because of the bellow code in the `Parent`, the state sets with old data(which comes from parent).

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.userId !== prevState.userId)
      return {
        userId : this.props.userId
      }
    return null
  } 
@Agney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the state in `Parent` to change when a value in `Grandparent` changes, then the quickest way forward would be to use `componentDidUpdate`:

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userId : this.props.userId
    }
  }
  getDataFromChild(value){
    this.setState({
      userId: value
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.userId !== this.props.userId) {
      this.setState({
        userId: this.props.userId,
      });
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <Child onChange={(value) => this.getDataFromChild(value)} />
    )
  }
}
```

If, on the other hand, if you don't want state in `Parent` to change once the user has set it to something, then you can manually set a state that indicates that `Child` has set it and use it in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
getDataFromChild(value){
  this.setState({
    userId: value,
    setByChild: true,
  })
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(!this.state.setByChild && prevProps.userId !== this.props.userId) {
    this.setState({
      userId: this.props.userId,
    });
  }
}
```

Related:
[You don't need derived state - React Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)